# MoveModifier while rotating in Andengine

Tags: andengine

Im trying to make the drawback of a gun, for this the gun should rotate a little bit and go back too, then it should go front a little bit (simulating the repositioning if the shooter).

Doing this with MoveByModier requires changing it in every manageUpdate and some trigonometry. If i dont do it this way i could do it with 2 routes (one Modifier for the pull and another the repositioning ) but its still hard

[image: This is a 2 points animation, the rectangle displaces to one point,and then to another]

So, Is there a MoveModifier that its independent from position AND rotation?

Comment: I understand that you want to animate the gun movement while the shooter still moves, so gun should move regarding the shooter position not the scene?

Comment: The shooter doesnt move, i want to animate the gun so that moving while it is in angle means  `move (cos (angle))*value, (sin(angle)*value))` in scene terms. If it helps i ll post an image

Comment: A modifier that for example `MoveAModifier(1,20,0)` will move right if `sprite.getRotation()`=0,  wil go up if `sprite.getRotation()`=90 and so

Comment: I think there is no suck modifier, but it is possible with some math.

Comment: Yes, if the rotation is constant, but How do i do it if im using a Rotation modifier at the same time?

Comment: There is something like ParallelEntityModifier which can run few modifiers at the same time

Comment: I been searching about it but i cant unerstand. Whats the difference beetwen ParallelEntityModifier and registering 2 by sepaete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time i figured out how to make the 2 points animation.

```
public void drawback (Sprite sprite, float DeltaAngle, float drawback){
    Vector2 center= new Vector2(sprite.getRotationCenterX(),sprite.getRotationCenterY());
    Vector2 radiusPoint = new Vector2(sprite.getWidth(),sprite.getHeight());
    float radius = radiusPoint.dst(center)/PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT;

    Vector2 currentPosition= new Vector2(sprite.getX(),sprite.getY());

    Vector2 pointA = new Vector2(
            (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(DeltaAngle/2+180))*drawback   +  Float.valueOf (sprite.getX()),
            (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(DeltaAngle/2+180))*drawback   +  Float.valueOf (sprite.getY())  );

    Vector2 pointB = new Vector2(
            (float) Math.cos (Math.toRadians((DeltaAngle)))*radius +  Float.valueOf (sprite.getX()),
            (float) Math.sin (Math.toRadians((DeltaAngle)))*radius +  Float.valueOf (sprite.getY()) );



    sprite.registerEntityModifier(new ParallelEntityModifier(
            new RotationByModifier(2,15),
            new SequenceEntityModifier(
                    new PathModifier(.5f,new PathModifier.Path(
                            new float[]{currentPosition.x,pointA.x},
                            new float[]{currentPosition.y,pointA.y}))),
                    new PathModifier(1.5f,new PathModifier.Path(
                            new float[]{pointA.x,pointB.x},
                            new float[]{pointA.y,pointB.y}))
    ));}
```

I belive the trygonometry can be simplified, but i will leave it to a curious commenter